# LINQ to XML get elements in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml structure:

```
<section id="section1">
 <section id="section2"/>
 <section id="section3"/>
</section>
<section id="section4"/>
```

How can I get the id's of the sections in section1. The result should be section2 and section3.

I tried this method but I get the result "section1":

```
var sectionsinsection1 = from x in xdocument.Descendants("section")
                         where x.Attribute("id").Value == "section1"
                         select x.Attribute("id").Value;
```

Comment: You're saying "For all the sections with an "id" attribute with a value of "section1", tell me the "id" attribute value" - so yes, it's going to give you "section1". You're selecting the same thing you're filtering on. Is `section1` always at the top? If so, consider a nested query of `from parent in xdocument.Elements("section") where (string) parent.Attribute("id") == "section1" from child in parent.Elements("section") select (string) child.Attribute("id")`

Comment: This method works. I couldn't come up with the subquery. But it's always like that. I need to know the ID of those childs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Objects of `XDocument` type need to have a root, so I'm checking for the parent of sections other than document root.

```
var sectionsinsection1 = from s in xdocument.Descendants("section")
                         where s.Parent != s.Document.Root 
                               && s.Parent.Attribute("id").Value == "section1"
                         select s.Attribute("id").Value;
```